# Apache 2.4 - mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, apache, out-of-memory

Apache 2.4.17 32-bit on Windows 10 x64, FCGI/PHP 7.0.4 32-bit. I am fighting with the error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 117440512) (tried to allocate 201326600 bytes) in ...
```

There is many advices but nothing works. Are there more parameters that can affect it? My settings are:

PHP.INI:
memory_limit = 1500M ; confirmed in phpinfo()

HTTPD.CONF:
RLimitMEM 1500000000 1500000000

(RLimitMEM max max # didnt work too)

My physical memory is 12GB and 5.5 GB is permanently free.
I think this error didn't appear in Apache 2.2. I always needed memory limit greather than 500MB. Only one customer needs export to big CSV. The error occurs by concatenating strings. But I am concatenating always only 1 row and immediately writing it using fputcsv() into tempfile. One row reaches maximum 1-2 KB. I don't know about any variable that can grow over many megabytes.

Maybe memory leak or bad garbage collector in PHP 7?

Comment: Please note that *Out of memory* is basically a PHP crash, not to be confused with *Maximum execution time exceeded*.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention any execution time exceeding. My time limit is set to 1000 sec (FcgidIOTimeout 1000) and the error occurs in 1 minute. This is memory exhausting. It seems memory_limit and rLimitMEM are not the only parameters you can set. Do you know any other? Upgrading to PHP 7.0.7 didnt help.

Comment: Since it's a plain crash (rather than a controlled shut-down), I doubt you can increase any parameter to fix it.